# how to run docker with keycloak image as a daemon in prod environment

Tags: shell, docker, wildfly, daemon, keycloak

I am using docker to run my Keycloak server in aws production environment. The problem is keycloak uses wildfly which is constant running. Because of this I cannot close the shell. I am trying to find a way to run docker as a daemon thread.

The command I use to run docker

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jboss/keycloak
```

Answer (score 2):

Just user docker's detach option **-d**.
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -d jboss/keycloak`

Comment: This gets uglier for docker-compose, as you have to run docker-compose in detached mode and it's a global setting not a per-service setting.  What firefly/keycloak are doing is a docker anti-pattern